# Redirect disabled product to product category

Tags: product, 404-page

I would like to know if it's possible to **redirect** disabled product to the **URL of its category**.

Comment: Please specify Magento's version to get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an observer as explained in this article http://evgv.github.io/magento/redirect/categories/product/observer/2016/04/27/redirect-from-disabled-product-to-last-product-category.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this functionality using override `Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index` controller

Ref Link :https://www.integerbyteblog.in/technology/magento-2-redirect-disabled-product-to-other-url/